# How to tell if no result were matched using doctrine Criteria?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, criteria

I have number of blog posts in my database and im using doctrine criteria to filter them. If I write criteria that matches some of the posts everything works perfect.

Imagine that there are 3 users (User 1 , User 2, User 3) and there are some posts marked as private from User 1 and user 2.

This is my php code :

```
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->Where($criteria->expr()->eq('private', 1);
$criteria->andWhere($criteria->expr()->eq('author', $author));
$posts=$service->findPostBy($criteria);

return array(
            'page' => $page,
            'posts'=>$posts,
            'filter' => $form->createView()
            );

/*findPostBy calls Doctrine matching function*/
public function matching(Criteria $criteria)
    {
        $persister = $this->_em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister($this->_entityName);

        return new ArrayCollection($persister->loadCriteria($criteria));
    }
```

If i ask for User 1 private posts it builds functional query and return posts i want. But if I ask for User 3 private posts It returns all posts in my database without any filtering. How can I tell if my criteria works if they dont return empty result in case of no matches.

Comment: The Symfony profiler should show you the exact database queries that are being run and you can check them there

Comment: That is true but i need to tell user that there are no posts based on his filters. I need some variable or somethign that would alow me to inform user.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be checking when the query returns 0 results?

Comment: Point is that it does not return 0 results . It returns everything nomatter filters.

Comment: Right hence my first suggestion to use the Symfony profiler to make sure your criteria is actually being set on the queries

Comment: It seems they dont, 'where' statement in sql query is empty. What does it mean for me ?

Comment: I would post more code showing where you create the query and apply the criteria to it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('private', 1);
    ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq('author', $author));
```

I'm not sure why you are using criteria in the first place for your example though.  You could eliminate the Criteria altogether and accomplish what you want in one line:

```
$posts $service->findPostBy(array('private' => 1, 'author' => $author);
```

Comment: How can I simulate > and < operators in this array notation ?

Comment: If you mean greater than or less than, you'd have to use the query builder or DQL for cases like that. See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#querying

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out @kajacx?